# puppeteer semantic-ui-react dropdown how to select options

Tags: puppeteer, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

```
    <div role="listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-expanded="false" class="ui selection dropdown content--content-type:-selector" tabindex="0" style="width: 100%;"><div class="default text" role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">Select type</div><i aria-hidden="true" class="dropdown icon"></i><div class="menu transition"><div role="option" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="true" class="selected item" style=`enter code here`"pointer-events: all;"><span class="text">Single</span></div><div role="option" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false" class="item" style="pointer-events: all;"><span class="text">Multi</span></div><div role="option" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false" class="item" style="pointer-events: all;"></div></div></div>
```

Very beginner in puppeteer. I am looking to select dropdown options.

Comment: What approach have you tried so far that didn't work?

Comment: I am not sure how to do this. I see puppeteer docs have examples only about page.select but in this case there is no select class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no unique selector for the dropdown element - so you could grab it - then you can use an XPath with `contains(text(), {string})`, do the search inside the container tag, in this case it is the `<span>`. After we've grabbed the item a simple [`click`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v4.0.0&show=api-elementhandleclickoptions) will emulates that a real user selects the element.

(In the last three lines I've put a validation just to see if we've successfully selected the dropdown option.)

Let's see it in case of "Single" option:

```js
  const optionSingle = await page.$x('//span[contains(text(), "Single")]')
  await optionSingle[0].click()

  // if we did everything correctly the `'.selected, .item'` classes will be applied on the selected item
  const selectedItemInnerText = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, (await page.$$('.selected, .item'))[0])
  selectedItemInnerText === 'Single' ? console.log('We\'ve succesfully selected the item :)') : console.log('Something went wrong :(')
```

*Note:* You may need to click inside the listbox first. Obviously I don't see the CSS of your example so I cannot tell if this specific case requires it or the options can be selected without it.

*Suggestion:* Test out the XPath (or selector) in Chrome DevTools like this: `$x('//span[contains(text(), "Single")]')[0].click()`. If it does select the desired option: it will work in puppeteer as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanation. I am able to select option from dropdown. Using this code I was getting " Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement". So added to make list visible   await page.evaluate(() =>{
        document.querySelector('div[role="listbox"] > div[class="menu transition"]').click();
    });                And this works like a charm. :)

Comment: I am happy it works! Take time to read the official api docs: https://pptr.dev/, you will find puppeteer very useful. One more thing: instead of the `document.querySelector` I recommend to use some more puppeteer-ish solution like: `await page.click('.menu, .transition')` ;)

Comment: Sure, will definitely follow your suggestion. On this page there are two dropdown with menu transition. I need to think how uniquely can select current dropdown. I am also more curious to know best practices to design test automation framework. If you have any detail, please let me know.

Comment: Able to click dropdown using   `await page.click('.selection');`